# c# Insert '-' between numbers for BSB

Tags: c#-4.0, string-formatting

I need to convert this number 0331234 to 033-1234 so that it's formatted as Bank BSB number.

Is there a smart way to achieve this apart of string.substring etc.?

Comment: try this `YourString.Insert(3, "-")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Custom Numeric Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int value = 0331234;
value.ToString("[000-0000]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    string str = "0331234";
    string newstr = str.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + str.Substring(3);
```